# Rationalising term

Tags: rationalising-denominator

What will be the rationalizing term for $30\sqrt 2 + 24 + 20 \sqrt 6$? It cannot be $30 \sqrt 2 - 20\sqrt 6$. Neither can it be $30 \sqrt 2+ 20 \sqrt 6 - 24$ because the product of these with the denominator will again contain a square root.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please, use Latex

Comment: Please use Mathjax. Also show what you've tried and point out where you are having trouble.

Comment: @NombreFalso123 Sorry i do not know mathjax or latex.

Comment: You don't need either to remove the unnecessary brackets. As for your question, multiply by $30\sqrt2+20\sqrt6−24$, and _then_ multiply by whatever it takes to remove the remaining sqrt.

Answer (score 0):

Take $(30\sqrt2+24+20\sqrt6)\times(a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6)$
$=30a\sqrt2+60b+30c\sqrt6+60d\sqrt3+24a+24b\sqrt2+24c\sqrt3+24d\sqrt6+20a\sqrt6+40b\sqrt3+60c\sqrt2+120d$
$=(60b+24a+120d)+(30a+24b+60c)\sqrt2+(60d+24c+40b)\sqrt3+(30c+24d+20a)\sqrt6$

From this, we get
$$5a+4b+10c=0$$
$$15d+6c+10b=0$$
$$15c+12d+10a=0$$
Since we have $4$ variables and $3$ equations, we need to assume some value. Say $a=1$
$$b={{245}\over{604}}, c={{-100}\over{151}}, b={{-5}\over{906}}$$
Since multiplying won't affect rationalisation, let us multiply all 4 variables by  $1812$.
$$a=1812, b=735, c=-1200, d=-10$$
Therefore, your rationalising factor is $(1812+735\sqrt2-1200\sqrt3-10\sqrt6)$

Comment: I realise it's a messy answer, but this is the only surefire way to get the answer.